# ImportError when using pyteomics and cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have a large script which I need to compile into an .exe executable which uses the pyteomics module. The setup script "build_script.py" (conventionally named "setup.py") looks like this:

```
import sys
from os import environ
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
# Set the TCL and TK library explicitly (it seems like the python 3.6 causes
# errors otherwise):
environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\tcl\tk8.6'


#Inclusion of dll files to fix tkinter import:
include_files = [r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\tcl86t.dll', \
                 r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\tk86t.dll']
#Inclusion of modules that need to be explicitly imported for some reason:
packages = ['pyteomics']

#Dependencies that are not implicitly detected:
build_exe_options = {'includes': [], 
                     'include_files': include_files, 
                     'packages': packages}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

setup(  name = 'Davidek beta 1.1.1',
        version = '1.1.1',
        options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable('Davidek.py', base=base)])
```

As you can see, I have tried to explicitly import pyteomics as a package, but it still gives the same error message:

```
    (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Max\Scilifelab\Projects\Master thesis\Davidek\Code>python build_script.py build
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_script.py", line 39, in <module>
    executables = [Executable('Davidek.py', base=base)])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 621, in Freeze
    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 340, in _GetModuleFinder
    finder.IncludePackage(name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 653, in IncludePackage
    module = self._ImportModule(name, deferredImports)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 350, in _ImportModule
    raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name)
ImportError: No module named 'pyteomics'
```

I am using Python 3.6.0 on 64-bit Windows 10.

Edit upon request:

Here is the specific script that imports pyteomics:

```
from pyteomics import mass

#Carbon isotopic label weight:
Cmass = 13.0033548378 - 12
Nmass = 15.0001088982 - 14.0030740048
#IAA added weight:
IAAmass = 57.02146


def calculate_mass(sequence, charge, ionType, IAA):
    """ Calculates and returns the monoisotopic mass of an ion.

    >>> calculate_mass('PEPTIDECK', 1, 'y', 1)
    1088.4928482921898
    >>> calculate_mass('PEPTIDECK', 1, 'b', 1)
    1070.48228360849
    >>> calculate_mass('PEPTIDECK', 1, 'y', 0)
    1031.4713882921899
    >>> calculate_mass('PEPTIDECK', 2, 'y', 1)
    544.7500623794799
    """
    monoisotopicMass = mass.calculate_mass(sequence, charge=charge, ion_type=ionType)
    if IAA: 
        monoisotopicMass += IAAmass*sequence.count('C')/charge

    return monoisotopicMass

def calculate_heavyShift(sequence, labels):
    """ Calculates and returns the mass shift of a heavy peptide given the sequence.

    >>> calculate_heavyShift("PEPTIDECK", 'K:0C2N, R:0C2N')
    1.9940697868000008
    """
    #Count number of K and R in sequence:
    Knum = sequence.count('K')
    Rnum = sequence.count('R')
    #Calculate mass shift:
    Kmass = int(labels.split(',')[0].split(':')[1][0])*Cmass + int(labels.split(',')[0].split(':')[1][2])*Nmass
    Rmass= int(labels.split(' ')[1].split(':')[1][0])*Cmass + int(labels.split(' ')[1].split(':')[1][2])*Nmass
    return Kmass*Knum + Rmass*Rnum

def calculate_fragmentPeakCluster(sequence, charge, IAA, maxClusterPeaks, labels, ionType, includedPeaks):
    """ Calculates and returns a dictionary of the peak cluster of a certain fragment.

    >>> calculate_fragmentPeakCluster('PEPTIDECK', 1, 1, 3, 'K:0C2N, R:0C2N', 'y', ['l0','l1','l2','h0'])=={'y9 l1+': 1089.49620312999, 'y9 l0+': 1088.4928482921898, 'y9 l2+': 1090.4995579677898, 'y9 h0+': 1090.48691807899}
    True

    """
    monoisotopicMass = calculate_mass(sequence, charge, ionType, IAA)
    heavyShift = calculate_heavyShift(sequence, labels)
    fragmentNumber = len(sequence)

    fragmentCluster = {}

    lightID = ' l'
    #b-fragments are the same mass whether from heavy or light origins:
    if ionType=='b':
        lightID=' '

    #Parse through peaks in isotopic order:
    for peakNumber in range(maxClusterPeaks):
        #Calculate light peak m/z:

        if 'l'+str(peakNumber) in includedPeaks:
            lightPeakMass = monoisotopicMass + peakNumber*Cmass/charge
            fragmentCluster[ionType + str(fragmentNumber) + lightID +str(peakNumber) + '+'*charge] = lightPeakMass
        #Calculate heavy peak m/z. Not for 'b'-ions
        if not ionType=='b':
            if 'h'+str(peakNumber) in includedPeaks:
                heavyPeakMass = lightPeakMass + heavyShift/charge
                fragmentCluster[ionType + str(fragmentNumber) + ' h' +str(peakNumber) + '+'*charge] = heavyPeakMass

    return fragmentCluster



def calculate_precursorPeakCluster(sequence, charge, maxClusterPeaks, labels, IAA=False):
    """ Calculate and returns the m/z of the precursor's isotope cluster.

    #No IAA/CAA:
    >>> calculate_precursorPeakCluster("PEPTIDECK", 1, 3, 'K:0C2N, R:0C2N', IAA=False)=={'l0': 1031.4713882921899, 'l1': 1032.47474312999, 'h1': 1034.46881291679, 'h2': 1035.47216775459, 'l2': 1033.4780979677898, 'h0': 1033.46545807899}
    True

    #With IAA/CAA:
    >>> calculate_precursorPeakCluster("PEPTIDECK", 1, 3, 'K:0C2N, R:0C2N', IAA=True)=={'l0': 1088.4928482921898, 'l1': 1089.49620312999, 'h1': 1091.49027291679, 'h2': 1092.4936277545899, 'l2': 1090.4995579677898, 'h0': 1090.48691807899}
    True

    #With IAA/CAA and charge 2:
    >>> calculate_precursorPeakCluster("PEPTIDECK", 2, 3, 'K:0C2N, R:0C2N', IAA=True)=={'l0': 544.7500623794799, 'l1': 545.25173979838, 'h1': 546.24877469178, 'h2': 546.7504521106799, 'l2': 545.7534172172799, 'h0': 545.74709727288}
    True

    """
    precursorCluster = {}
    #Calculate the monoisotopic mass over charge:
    monoisotopicMass = calculate_mass(sequence, charge, 'y', IAA)
    #Calculate peak mass over charges for every peaknumber:
    for peakNumber in range(maxClusterPeaks):
        #Calculate light peak m/z:
        lightPeakMass = monoisotopicMass + peakNumber*Cmass/charge
        precursorCluster['l'+str(peakNumber)] = lightPeakMass
        #Calculate heavy peak m/z
        heavyShift = calculate_heavyShift(sequence, labels)
        heavyPeakMass = lightPeakMass + heavyShift/charge
        precursorCluster['h'+str(peakNumber)] = heavyPeakMass       

    return precursorCluster


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

The tree structure of pyteomics looks like this:

```
C:.
|   achrom.py
|   auxiliary.py
|   electrochem.py
|   fasta.py
|   featurexml.py
|   mgf.py
|   mzid.py
|   mzml.py
|   mzxml.py
|   parser.py
|   pepxml.py
|   pylab_aux.py
|   tandem.py
|   xml.py
|
+---mass
|   |   mass.py
|   |   unimod.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |
|   \---__pycache__
|           mass.cpython-36.pyc
|           unimod.cpython-36.pyc
|           __init__.cpython-36.pyc
|
+---openms
|   |   featurexml.py
|   |   trafoxml.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |
|   \---__pycache__
|           featurexml.cpython-36.pyc
|           trafoxml.cpython-36.pyc
|           __init__.cpython-36.pyc
|
\---__pycache__
        achrom.cpython-36.pyc
        auxiliary.cpython-36.pyc
        electrochem.cpython-36.pyc
        fasta.cpython-36.pyc
        featurexml.cpython-36.pyc
        mgf.cpython-36.pyc
        mzid.cpython-36.pyc
        mzml.cpython-36.pyc
        mzxml.cpython-36.pyc
        parser.cpython-36.pyc
        pepxml.cpython-36.pyc
        pylab_aux.cpython-36.pyc
        tandem.cpython-36.pyc
        xml.cpython-36.pyc
```

Comment: can u show the folder in tree structure of pyteomics package and your .py which u are running

Comment: I have edited my query to your request. My program is split in many scripts, but I have attached the one which uses pyteomics. Let me know if I should add anything else!